# Crear código de barras

Tags: php, javascript, html

Necesito crear un código de barras, que sea algo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

no importa si es en html, js, php.. solo necesito que se pueda ver.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes usar: https://lindell.me/JsBarcode/ y generar los códigos tu mismo o con algún otro script que los genere en base a lo que necesites (ej: ISBN).

```js
JsBarcode(".barcode").init();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jsbarcode/3.6.0/JsBarcode.all.min.js"></script>
<svg class="barcode"
  jsbarcode-format="upc"
  jsbarcode-value="123456789012"
  jsbarcode-textmargin="0"
  jsbarcode-fontoptions="bold">
</svg>
```

Comment: no me funciona ninguno de los 3 ejemplos de esa página.

Comment: A mi me funciona, puedes entender su funcionamiento con la herramienta inspeccionar del navegador.

Comment: este es el orden correcto?

<script src="JsBarcode.all.min.js"></script>

<svg id="barcode"></svg>

JsBarcode("#barcode", "Hi world!");

Comment: `<svg class="barcode" data-value="Hi world!" width="288px" height="142px" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 288 142" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255);">` ... Tomado de inspeccionar

Comment: ...............

Comment: La etiqueta HTML lo que hace es usar la clase Barcode. [Github con mas explicacion](https://github.com/lindell/JsBarcode/)